# My program works but Codeacademy does not acknowledge

Tags: python

Here is my code for the pig latin translator.  It works both on Code academy and in linux terminal.

```
pyg = 'ay'
new_word = pyg

original = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    original.lower()
    word = original
    first = original[0]
    if first  == 'a' or first =='e' or first == 'i' or first =='o' or first == 'u':
        print 'vowel'

    elif first != 'a' or first !='e' or first !='o' or first !='i' or first !='u':


        print  word.lower()[1:] + first +new_word 

else:
    print 'empty'
```

Code academy gives following result;
Oops, try again! Your word started with a consonant, but “ay' was printed instead of “ogday”. Make sure the correct value #is stored in “new_word”.

"ay" is not printed but "ogday' is printed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I cannot continue with Codeacademy as without solving this.

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels ...

Comment: off-topic: `original.lower()` is useless, strings are immutable(assign the result back to the variable). The long `if` condition can be reduced to : `if first in ['a','e','i','o','u']`.

Comment: Well, you're not storing anything beside "ay" in the `new_word` variable, and it clearly expects you to. Have you tried setting this variable?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary why make that a list? Just `'aeiou'` would do...

Comment: Just for safety: That may still match `'ae'`, if OP gets the `first = original[0]` part wrong. (But for current code just 'aeiou' is also fine).

Comment: I realize the code could be simpler.  I do it the way Codeacademy asks.  The code does work even in Codeacademy compiler but not acknowledged.  I was hoping someone had experience with the academy and knew what had to be done to get the Academy to accept it.

Comment: Did you just not bother reading this bit: `Make sure the correct value #is stored in “new_word”.`

Comment: Sorry Paul i just saw the answers of how the code needed to be changed.  I was instructed to assign pyg to new_word

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for example. You are in the right track just use what you have learned in the Code academy up to this task.

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz"
original = raw_input('Enter a word: ')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
   if original.lower()[0] in 'aeiou':
      print original.lower() + 'ay'
   else:
      keep_first_consonants = ''
      count = 0
      for letter in original.lower():
          if letter in consonants:
             keep_first_consonants = keep_first_consonants + letter
             count += 1
          else:
             break
      total_characters = len(original.lower())
      print original.lower()[count:total_characters] + keep_first_consonants + 'ay'
else:
    print 'Accept only letters'
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for the replies.  This is the code i finally got to work. I know it is messy and could be done easier and simpler.  Code academy requires certain parts certain ways or it won't pass.  Well i could not post the code as it was too long.

Answer (score 0):

The codeacademy lesson checker seems to check the variable new_word when you hit run

So you just need to use new_word for both your print varibles

This code works:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    if first == "a" or first == "e" or first == "i" or first == "o" or first == "u":
        new_word = original + pyg
        print new_word
    else:
        newer_word = word[1:]
        new_word = newer_word + first + pyg
        print new_word
```